# Mixed mouse themes

Tags: unity, mouse, themes, icons, cursor

I have a problem with my mouse cursor theme style. Sometimes, it shows the theme I downloaded, sometimes the default Ubuntu theme (depending on which window I´m on). I already tried:

- Installed cursor themes with the Ubuntu software center
- Installed cursor themes from several websites and saved it into `~/.icons`
- Installed cursor themes from several websites and saved it into `/usr/share/icons`
- Tried some commands I found online

Anyone any tips? I am using Ubuntu LTS 14.04

Comment: Indeed it happens in Unity DE, when navigate to a browser window for example it becomes the default white cursor, no clue how to change it, probably needs some adjustments in Unity X window managing or fix. It doesn't happen in XFCE, Gnome though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install [dconf tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/):

   `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
2. Start it with `dconf-editor &`
3. Head to **org >> gnome >> desktop >> interface** and select your cursor theme.
4. Open a terminal and enter the command:

   `sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme`
5. Select the number that corresponds to your choice
6. Reboot your system

The reason why the cursor theme only showed up on some applications was because the cursor wasn't configured to run over *all* applications.

Comment: I am using Unity tweak tool since I'm  using default unity. Or are you aware of that and I have to try it with GNOME tweak tool?

Comment: Yes, that's right :) The tool will partly install GNOME shell as it requires such dependencies, but nothing to worry about

Comment: unfortunately, that did not work.

Comment: Okay, I've modified the answer to include another way.

Comment: Thank you. Firstly, it didn't work again. Then I got suspicious and reinstalled my themes. After that I did the steps above again and now it works. Can't upvote yet, sorry ;(